# Unable to imlement drag and drop

Tags: android

I am trying to make a alphabet exam. I have a `ImageView11` which shows the a random alphabet which you have to guess. And the `imageView_alphabet_image_1` and `imageView_alphabet_image_2` will show two options which I have to guess and I will drag the `ImageView11` image on correct `ImageView` which is showing down. But I'm able to do it for only first time when i click on refresh it always showing incorrect toast

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Refresh"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dragLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView_des"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView_alphabetImage_1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView_alphabetImage_2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```html
package com.example.cleardoubt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener,
  OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

 private ImageView _imgView_des;
 private ImageView _imgView_alphabetImage_1;
 private ArrayList<Integer> _alphabet_arrayList;
 private Button _btn_refresh;
 private ImageView _imgView_alphabetImage_2;
 private ArrayList<Integer> _tempArrayList;
 private ArrayList<Integer> _finalTempArrayList;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  initView();
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  _imgView_des = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView_des);
  _imgView_des.setOnClickListener(this);
  _imgView_des.setOnTouchListener(this);
  _imgView_des.setOnDragListener(this);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView_alphabetImage_1);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_1.setOnClickListener(this);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_1.setOnDragListener(this);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView_alphabetImage_2);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_2.setOnClickListener(this);
  _imgView_alphabetImage_2.setOnDragListener(this);
  _btn_refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
  _btn_refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 private void initView() {
  _alphabet_arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.a);
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.b);
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.c);
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.d);
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.e);
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.f); 
  _alphabet_arrayList.add(R.drawable.g); 
  
  _tempArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  _finalTempArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.imgView_des:

   break;
  case R.id.imgView_alphabetImage_1:
   if (_imgView_des
     .getDrawable()
     .getConstantState()
     .equals(_imgView_alphabetImage_1.getDrawable()
       .getConstantState())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "not  matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   break;

  case R.id.imgView_alphabetImage_2:
   if (_imgView_des
     .getDrawable()
     .getConstantState()
     .equals(_imgView_alphabetImage_2.getDrawable()
       .getConstantState())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "not  matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   
   break;
   
  case R.id.btn_refresh:
   
   Random random = new Random();
   int index = random.nextInt(7);
   _imgView_des.setImageResource(_alphabet_arrayList.get(index));
   _imgView_des.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   _tempArrayList = (ArrayList<Integer>) _alphabet_arrayList.clone();
   _tempArrayList.remove(index);
   Collections.shuffle(_tempArrayList, random);
   for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    _finalTempArrayList.add(_tempArrayList.get(j));
   }
   _finalTempArrayList.add(_alphabet_arrayList.get(index));
   Collections.shuffle(_finalTempArrayList);
   Log.e(" _finalTempArrayList after suffel", _finalTempArrayList.toString());
   _imgView_alphabetImage_1.setImageResource(_finalTempArrayList.get(0));
   _imgView_alphabetImage_2.setImageResource(_finalTempArrayList.get(1));
   _finalTempArrayList.clear();
   break;
   
  default:
   break;
  }

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
  if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   // ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
   DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
   v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
   v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
  switch (e.getAction()) {

  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
   // if (e.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
   // ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
   // return true;
   // } else {
   // Toast.makeText(this, "can not accept the image",
   // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   //
   // }

   // return false;
   break;

  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
   if (_imgView_des
     .getDrawable()
     .getConstantState()
     .equals(_imgView_alphabetImage_1.getDrawable()
       .getConstantState())) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    viewGroup.removeView(_imgView_des);
    v.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
    return true;
    
   } 
   else if(_imgView_des
     .getDrawable()
     .getConstantState()
     .equals(_imgView_alphabetImage_2.getDrawable()
       .getConstantState()))
   {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    viewGroup.removeView(_imgView_des);
    v.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
    return true; 
   }
//   else {
//    return false;
//   }
  
   break;
   
   
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
   Log.v("a", e.getResult() + "");
   if (e.getResult()) {
    _imgView_des.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.v("asddd", e.getResult() + "");
    Toast.makeText(this, " accept the image",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
   } else {
    _imgView_des.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast toast = new Toast(this);
       ImageView view = new ImageView(this); 
       view.setImageResource(R.drawable.unsuccess); 
       toast.setView(view); 
       toast.show();
       return true;
   }

  

  default:
   break;
  }
  return false;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked you code the problem is in your **onDrag** method.

case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP event did not call because of you did not return flag case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: event. You have to pass true flag like below code

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

return true;
```

Comment: after writting true it also accept the wrong alphabet image and it is showing the toast two times

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh - you have only check the drawable of imageview. Did not calculated the position of dragged imageview. so if you drag image over _imgView_alphabetImage_1 then after it will check both imageview. so you need to check first user drag image over which image view.